# How to add data to object

Tags: javascript, object

I am trying to adddata from another object into a new object while also adding new data
`const addCardData =  { ...optIn, cardId, cardName}` 
here optIn already has cardId and cardName so they are getting replaced by new values, how to make an addCardData such that cardId and cardName not be replaced but added to the object or as a sub object? or is there any other better way to do this?

Comment: Reverse the spread order

Comment: hi perhaps skip certain properties when merging the data, or make certain properties a list of values

Comment: Thank you it's working once i reversed the order

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a way to combine both objects. If any of the properties already exists in `optIn` it will be changed into an array in `addCardData` and the new value will then be pushed onto it:

```js
const optIn={a:123,b:456,cardId:789,cardName:"Harry"},cardId=222,cardName="Sally";

const addCardData = {...optIn};
Object.entries({cardId,cardName}).forEach(([k,v])=>{
 (addCardData[k]=Array.isArray(addCardData[k])?addCardData[k]:[addCardData[k]]).push(v)
});

console.log(addCardData);
```

Comment: thanks!!! i wanted to know how to do it for a much simpler case but glad to learn something new!!!

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to keep the values from "optIn", you could add them last.

For example:

```js
addCardData =  { 
  cardId, 
  cardName, 
  ...optIn 
};
```

If your goal is to add **both** versions of cardId and **both** versions of cardName, you have two options:

1. Change the name of cardId and cardName, since an object can only old one attribute with a given name.

For example:

```js
addCardData =  { 
  newCardId: cardId, 
  newCardName: cardName, 
  ...optIn 
};
```

2. Add the optIn object as an attribute

```js
addCardData =  { 
  cardId, 
  cardName, 
  optIn
};
```

Then you can refer to it by `addCardData.optIn.cardId`.

Comment: But in either cases I cannot do similar adddata operation again as it would cause further nesting, any way to avoid this?

Comment: I'm trying to understand exactly what you are needing.
If you want to throw out the old data each time, just set addCardData to optIn.

Answer (score 0):

so converting optIn to a array first and then doing optIn.push({cardId, cardName}) works perfectly without creating any nested objects

Comment: IMHO, manipulating as object would be a better outcome, instead of manipulating as array.  You need just a merge with a rule to prioritize new data or old data. Is that the case?

Answer (score 0):

The main goal is just merge? I mean, merge choosing between new data or old data? Here is a sample code showing both cases:

```
    const cardId = 999;
    const cardName = "Anakin";
    const optIn = {a:123, b:456, cardId:789, cardName:"Skywalker"}
    
    console.log({ ...optIn, cardId, cardName}); // merge applying new data on cardId/cardName
    console.log({ cardId, cardName, ...optIn}); // merge keeping original data on cardId/cardName
```

Comment: I wanted to merge in such a way that cardId nd cardName already existing in optIn not get replaced by new cardId nd cardName but get added as another object?